# How to write out semicolon-separated csv file with sqlite3 from Terminal

Tags: csv, select, sqlite, terminal

I'm using the `sqlite3` command line tool in Terminal on the Mac. 
The following commands will write out the content of TableA to a comma-separated csv file and place it on the desktop.

```
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .once /Users/AccountName/Desktop/dataout.csv
sqlite> SELECT * FROM TableA;
```

But how would I write if I wanted the result to be a *semicolon-separated* csv file?

The reason why I'm asking is that TableA includes comma-signs, so the default behavior will create a cvs file of jibberish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.separator` like this before your `SELECT`:

```
.separator ";"
```

Comment: Thanks,  very simple.